# Radio in the break room. Good or bad?

Tags: professionalism, work-environment

This isn't a big  deal, but I work a graveyard shift with about 5 other people, two of whom come in at 3am (I come in at 9pm).

My colleague and I both like to have jazz on in the kitchen.  There's a person who's coming in (someone I don't know well at all, not a longtime colleague) who's been turning it off.  Since there aren't many people here it was easy to figure out who is doing it.

No one hangs out in the kitchen, people just go in to refill their coffee (that seems important).  No one actually takes breaks in there.

This morning, after this happened, I turned the radio back on. I put it on a classical station as not everyone likes jazz.  I also turned it down a few notches.  And, then, she turned it off again.

This just feels weird to me.  For now I have decided that, while I'm still here, I'm just going to turn the thing back on again.

It's just really helpful to have some sound in the office. During the day, there are people talking, but at night it is really quiet. I am having a really hard time figuring out why jazz or classical music at low volume should be such a problem for someone (anyone) spending 60 to 90 seconds in a room getting coffee.  It feels like this person is kind of messing with me, or us. Anyway I just want the music on and I'm having trouble finding an adult, productive way to address this.

**How can I let my coworker know I would like the music on without a direct confrontation?**

Comment: Perhaps this is a candidate for migration to the Interpersonal Skills stack exchange?

Comment: So what is your question exactly? Have tried asking the person why they are turning off the radio?

Comment: I don't particularly like hearing music while I work.  She may not either...

Comment: Is it possible they where just environmentally conscious? Having the radio play for an essentially empty kitchen the whole night might seem like a waste to them.

Comment: Can you hear the music from your desk, or are you only hearing it during the 60 to 90 seconds when **you** get coffee? If having it on for you during that time is so valuable, then you should be able to understand why having it off for someone else during that time would also be valuable. Is there something preventing listening to music at your desk with headphones or small speakers?

Comment: I'm not surprised you're having a hard time figuring out your coworker if you don't want to communicate with them...

Comment: What value does having music on while you get a coffee refill or what ever other short task you are going to provide in the break room provide? Does it really do anything other then use electricity to have a radio on in a room where no one will hear it most of the time?

Comment: *"It's just really helpful to have some sound in the office."* Fair point, I know the "ghost town" feeling when there are few people in the office and it is quite uncomfortable working in such atmosphere, so I can empathise with you there. Now, how is leaving the music on in the coffee room going to help with this? Do you work from the coffee room, or is the sound from the coffee room audible in your work area? Most importantly, why did the powers-that-be place a radio in the coffee room to begin with, if it isn't supposed to be used? Could you please clarify these points?

Comment: Too short for an actual answer. The problem is probably jazz, find a radio station that plays symphonic metal and you won't hear me complain any more. (seriously, why not just ask, she might like a quiet workplace)

Comment: Sorry for multiple comments----length is limited. The main thing is that the work stations are not near the kitchen. So the music should not interfere with concentration. I would understand perfectly if it were. 
However it is a boon to three of us out of five who are there at this time, because I have asked the ones I know, what they think. I may just leave a note on it with my name and asking to come see me if it's a problem to have it on and we'll go from there.

Comment: To answer the question of *why* I didn't want to be confrontational: There are two people it might be. One I could absolutely ask. The other is his subordinate and she has not been there all that long. I don't know her, but I've overheard her saying things that gave me a lot of pause (I don't know if she knew I was listening).  I 1) don't like snitching .. And, 2)I don't like confronting people who are unknown quantities and possibly volatile, if I can avoid it.  Hope that clarifies the reasons for my question. Thanks again.  Symphonic metal would work for me & so would changing channel :)

Comment: I must be missing something here. **No one is in the kitchen and the music being on or off is an issue???** Turn it on when you enter, turn it off when you leave.

Comment: The title still seems to not match the question in the body of the post.

Comment: If the music is loud enough to affect your state of mind, presumably it's loud enough to affect her state of mind. In any case, we don't have to understand *why* it matters to her, to accept that it *does* matter to her.

Answer (score 24):

> It's just really helpful to have some sound in the office. During the day, there are people talking, but at night it is really quiet. Dead in here. I am having a really hard time figuring out why jazz or classical music at low volume should be such a problem for someone (anyone) spending 60 to 90 seconds in a room getting coffee.

I can think of multiple reasons why they might be turning it off:

1. They prefer quiet, fair enough you prefer the noise but they could very easily be of the opposite opinion
2. They don't see the point in leaving a radio on consuming power in a room that people are in for only 60-90 seconds at time while they make coffee. Heck, they might even be viewing that as doing people a favor!
3. They hate the music. Not everyone likes Jazz or Classical.
4. They are in fact messing with you - this one is possible but I'd say it's a big leap at this point.

But to be honest it's pretty pointless speculating without any other info.

> Anyway I just want the music on and I'm having trouble finding an adult, productive way to address this.

**Talk to them** - it doesn't have to be a confrontation, and nor should it. Just have a perfectly reasonable conversation with them and ask why they are doing it and see if you can work out a compromise

Comment: +1 If I'm leaving  an empty room I will turn off radio and lights

Comment: yes, could be just saving power, get a better resolution 'talking' to the person than online.

Answer (score 22):

> My colleague and I both like to have jazz on in the kitchen.

Great. But this is just the two of you. It doesn't mean that everyone else likes it. If I left heavy metal on every time I was in there because myself and another colleague of mine enjoyed it, would that be acceptable too?

> I am having a really hard time figuring out why jazz or classical music at low volume should be such a problem for someone (anyone) spending 60 to 90 seconds in a room getting coffee.

You can easily flip this on its head and say "I'm having a really hard time figuring out why this guy turns the radio on for the 60 seconds he's in the kitchen, then doesn't bother to turn it off again when he leaves."

There's all sorts of legitimate reasons. Perhaps a couple of others came in, wanted to have a conversation and didn't want the music on. Perhaps someone came in and thought, since no-one else was in there, it was a waste of electricity. Perhaps they're trying to concentrate or think of something, and it's a distraction. Perhaps they don't mind the music, but don't like the "chatter" that often goes in between tracks played on a radio station. Perhaps someone really hates both jazz and classical music.

I could go on, but suffice to say the chances are they're not just out to get you by turning off the radio.

There's a few easy things you could do to try to address the situation:

- Just talk to the guy in a non-confrontational manner, ask if he minds the radio being on, and if there's any other kind of music he'd prefer.
- Just keep the radio on when you and your colleague are in the kitchen. Turn it off when you leave.
- Bring some headphones to work and listen to some music in private (if that's an option.)

Comment: Yeah, I cannot see a radio as being a good idea in a break room.  Music taste vary as much as people themselves.

Answer (score 4):

> How can I let my coworker know I would like the music on without a direct confrontation?

You cannot really complain if someone turns off a radio playing in a room where nobody is listening to it. That seems an obvious thing to do. It looks like someone from the day-shift just forgot it.

So if you don't want to explain to people that you *want* a radio playing in an empty room for no audience, you could take ownership of the radio. Take the radio and put it on your desk. Problem solved, the person now has to come to you to turn it off.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to put a note to the radio not to turn it off during the day as continuous switching on and off is bad for the device. This is a reason to convince them.

I don't see a chance to enforce your view over the others' view because no one is more right than the other. The good news about this is it's not a personal confrontation or attack. It is simply different people living together. One leaves the radio on because he comes back, the other turns it off when leaving the room.

> No one hangs out in the kitchen ... No one actually takes breaks in there.

This is one more reason to turn the radio off when leaving.

Comment: "Okay, I won't switch it off, I'll just turn the volume down to zero then."

Comment: This could be a valid answer of course :-) Honestly is it such a big problem to not hear music if you are in the kitchen for some seconds to get coffee? (you described it that way)

Answer (score -1):

Compromise. No music. Talk radio is too opinionated. Since I think you are in the US, baseball radio is your solution. In the off session, Mark Twain audio books.